# What is the easiest way to validate page references? (css, javascript, etc..)

Tags: html, debugging

i've got firebug (my team does not have firefox), and the IE developer toolbar(IE7) but I can not seem to figure out how to easily validate if the referenced files in a page are loading (i see javascript errors, but that doesn't succinctly point me to the exact file in a heirarchy of jquery - jqueryUI - datepicker files).

Additionally i'd like to be able to do this remotely, because on our corporate domain some files load fine for me, but not anyone else because they sometimes get encrypted to my domain user. So it would be nice if this process was either simple enough for my teammates to do it very quickly, or ... even better somehow with automation from a remote machine or web service request.

I thought I had seen a simple place on firebug to validate what loaded and what did not, but I can't find it now.

What are my options?

Comment: apparently the Net tab in firebug is great for this, but I'm still looking for good automatable methods or where in the IE developer toolbar I could do it.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/lite (run on IE) don't fit your request but it's another good tool if you don't know it already.

Comment: thanks, I would have given you a +1 on that as an answer. I didn't know about it, and it should be useful, at the very least, useful to know about.

Answer (score 0):

do you tried [Javascript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php)?
Or the javascript plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: hmm this looks like it would be very nice, but I'm not sure how I would easily use it against .aspx files since they include server side asp code. Is there a way to force an asp compilation to a temp file?

Comment: Sorry, i don't work with ASP, but, if you get an ASP page in browser, do you get the code processed by server? if not, you can always copy and paste from the browser. :)

Answer (score 0):

do you know [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)?

It provides you with a set of excelent tools for web developing and I think it solves your question